# Vuex: Accessing state from anther module inside different module getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access state from another namespaced vuex modue inside getter in a different module, this is what I'm trying:

```
//GETTERS
const getters = {

    authorizedAdminLinks: ({ rootState }) =>  _.filter(rootState.globals.adminLinks, link => link.seePrivilege >= rootState.globals.auth.privileges),
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: rootState is undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

When defined in a module, a getter receives `rootState` as [a third argument](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#getters):

```
const getters = {
    authorizedAdminLinks: (state, getters, rootState) =>  _.filter(rootState.globals.adminLinks, link => link.seePrivilege >= rootState.globals.auth.privileges),
}
```